# Adding Single Backslash to Regex Pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

So I have a regex pattern:

```
no = 'C 030234(A) ZMM' 
pattern = '\d{1,2}(\s*)' + no
```

What I need to do is add a backslash before the ')' and '(' characters in the variable, no, to make the literals.

I tried something like

```
tList = []
for c in no:
  if np.logical_or(c=='(',c==')'):
    tList.append('\\'+c)
  else:
    tList.append(c)


no = "".join(tList)
pattern = '\d{1,2}(\s*) ' + no
```

But this yields a regex pattern of

```
'\d{1,2}(\s*)C 030234\\(A\\) ZMM'
```

I need to find away to any string in the form of *no*, and add a escape character before any parenthesis to make the proper regex pattern

```
'\d{1,2}(\s*)C 030234\(A\) ZMM'
```